# How Thread Pool handles static and dynamic requests in a web server?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, webserver, threadpool

There are two main types of requests arrive at web server ,first is static request that needs HTML page and second is dynamic e.g. a JSP page. A thread pool based web server assigns requests to the worker threads that are waiting in the pool to do some job. Does static and dynamic requests are both assign to the worker threads in the same thread pool or there are separate thread pools for both types of requests? How this scenario is handled in Apache?

Answer (score 0):

There's no sign the tomcat manual that there is a separate threadpool for the "default servlet" that handles static files and directory listings.